# Scraping Library for PHP - phpQuery?

Tags: php, screen-scraping, phpquery

I'm looking for a PHP library that allows me to scrap webpages and takes care about all the cookies and prefilling the forms with the default values, that's what annoys me the most.

I'm tired of having to match every single input element with xpath and I would love if something better existed. I've come across **phpQuery** but the manual isn't much clear and I can't find out how to make POST requests.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

**@Jonathan Fingland:**

In the example provided by the manual for browserGet() we have:

```
require_once('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');

phpQuery::browserGet('http://google.com/', 'success1');

function success1($browser)
{
    $browser->WebBrowser('success2')
    ->find('input[name=q]')->val('search phrase')
    ->parents('form')
    ->submit();
}

function success2($browser)
{
    echo $browser;
}
```

I suppose all the other fields are scrapped and send back in the GET request, I want to do the same with the phpQuery::browserPost() method but I don't know how to do it. The form I'm trying to scrape has a input token and I would love if phpQuery could be smart enough to scrape the token and just let me change the other fields (in this case username and password), submiting via POST everything.

**PS**: Rest assured, this is **not** going to be used for spamming.

Comment: +1 dont have an answer but look forward to others comments

Comment: If manual is not clear then you can try to read source code

Comment: Life's pretty tough for spammers these days.

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of webmasters and others who run thier own forums, etc. that will be perfectly happy if there is one less bot spammer out there.

Comment: Once again, you told you this is spam related?

Comment: I need to do this too, and it's not spam related..

Comment: It has to be noted that if one can use css selector, so he can use xpath and so can use the DOMDocument. It has not been embedded into php for spam usages, rather than to ease the life of the developers. All the guys questioning whether you are using this for spam or not are actually spamming the subject and should be flagged as spammers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Ajax and in particular:

`phpQuery::post($url, $data, $callback, $type)`

and

`# data Object, String` which defines the data parameter as being either an Object or a String. POST requests *should* be possible using query string format, e.g.:

```
$data = "username=Jon&password=123456";
$url = "http://www.mysite.com/login.php";
phpQuery::post($url, $data, $callback, $type)
```

as phpQuery is a jQuery port the method signature is the same (the docs link directly to the jquery site -- http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

**Edit**

Two things:

There is also a [`phpQuery::browserPost`](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/source/browse/trunk/phpQuery/phpQuery/plugins/WebBrowser.php#136) function which might meet your needs better.

However, also note that the success2 callback is only called on the [`submit()` or `click()`](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/source/browse/trunk/phpQuery/phpQuery/plugins/WebBrowser.php#30) methods so you can fill in all of the form fields prior to that.

e.g.

```
require_once('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
phpQuery::browserGet('http://www.mysite.com/login.php', 'success1');
function success1($browser) {
  $handle = $browser
    ->WebBrowser('success2');
  $handle 
    ->find('input[name=username]')
      ->val('Jon');
  $handle 
    ->find('input[name=password]')
      ->val('123456');
      ->parents('form')
        ->submit();
}
function success2($browser) {
  print $browser;
}
```

(Note that this has not been tested, but *should* work)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SimpleTest's ScriptableBrowser](http://www.lastcraft.com/browser_documentation.php) for such stuff in the past. It's part of the SimpleTest testing framework, but you can use it stand-alone.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dedicated library for parsing HTML files and a dedicated library for processing HTTP requests. Using the same library for both seems like a bad idea, IMO.

For processing HTTP requests, check out eg. [**`Httpful`**](http://phphttpclient.com/), [**`Unirest`**](http://unirest.io/php.html), [**`Requests`**](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) or [**`Guzzle`**](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/). Guzzle is especially popular these days, but in the end, whichever library works best for you is still a matter of personal taste.

For parsing HTML files I would recommend a library that I wrote myself : [**`DOM-Query`**](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query). It allows you to (1) load an HTML file and then (2) select or change parts of your HTML pretty much the same way you'd do it if you'd be using jQuery in a frontend app.