# Get content of a table from remote site

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I want to get the contents of a remote website using file_get_contents() This website has texts, images and a table in which i am interested. There is the next table on that remote site:

```
<table style="width: 100%" class="style36">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%" class="style38">B3</td>
        <td style="width: 60%" class="style38">Las Flores</td>
        <td style="width: 15%" class="style38">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The values on each cell are dynamic, and I would like to query them in the fastest and more reliable way possible.

I tried limiting the file_get_contents function to read only from X characters, but since the page is dynamic, I can not really know on which character my table starts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead.

Once you have the page's output, you can use a variety of tools to parse the content. Google will be your friend here, especially if you want to find a PHP HTML parser.

PHP has a ton of [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) functions at its disposal, so you could also roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at a concept call scraping; there are web scraping libraries available or you can you use preg_match_all() to get the elements you require with regular expressions.  [Scraping Library for PHP - phpQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644669/scraping-library-for-php-phpquery) check out that link.